# Spring 3.1 JSON data binding

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using JSON binding as following in my controller

```
public @ResponseBody Person getPerson(@RequestBody PersonReq req){
    // Some code here..
    ....
}
```

If for some reason the JSON request sent is invalid, then spring throws a very generic error.  Will I be able to gracefully handle this error?

What I want to do is something similar to form databinding where you can use BindingResult to capture the errors. (as shown below)

```
public String getPersonHtml(PersonReq req, BindingResult result){
    if (result.hasErrors()){
        // do error handling here..
    }
}
```

I tried similar approach by providing additional argument (BindingResult) but that didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fiddler to confirm that the JSON request is valid.

Comment: didn't help you? talk to me i want to help

Comment: My intention is to provide a friendly error message if the JSON request is invalid.  Alternatively i can get the JSON request as a string and then parse it using Jackson parser and catch the exception that it throws.